# How to import a module and change a variable value inside module and execute it

Tags: python, import, python-import, python-2.6

I have a module which I need to import and change particular variable values inside imported instance of that module and then execute it.

**Please note that** I can not make a single change to the module being imported due to legacy reasons.

Here is what I am trying to do:

say the module i want to import, a.py, looks like

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print var1+var2
```

Now I am importing this in b.py, the caller script. I am trying to import it, change value of variable var1 and run it as main program using runpy as follows.

```
import runpy
import a

a.var1 = 2
result = runpy._run_module_as_main(a.__name__)
```

But this prints result as `3` only and not as `4` as expected.

Any other way to achieve this (apart from using runpy) without changing anything in a.py? Open to any third party module as far as I dont have to make changes in module being imported.

I am using python 2.6

Comment: If you *really* want to do this, you're going to need the `ast` module, I believe.

Comment: @WayneWerner please let me know how

Comment: you *really* shouldn't do this and just use a class instead.

Comment: @XanderLuciano any way will do as far as I dont have to make changes to a.py

Comment: @MohitC then what you *probably* want to do is just duplicate whatever is inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block inside your own code, and simply mutate the values like you're already doing. There *shouldn't* be that much code in the block, unless it was terribly written.

Comment: @WayneWerner That cant be done as well as the code inside that part is not going to be known as well. This caller will execute many of such modules based on request. These modules which are being called hold one such variable which it imports from local file but i want to ovverride that import and set value to that variable externally from calling script

Comment: Are you sure you can't modify `a.py` in any way whatsoever? Simply moving the contents of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block into a `main` function wouldn't change the existing behavior, but it would let you modify the module's contents and then call `main` yourself.

Comment: "This caller will execute many of such modules based on request" - that would have been good to know earlier. "These modules which are being called hold one such variable which it imports from local file" - can you change the module these modules import?

Comment: Here's an idea. I am pretty sure the `runpy` module boils down to `exec .. in ..`. Try to replicate that functionality, and pass in a dict that is immune to changing values of `"var1`"

Comment: So you're saying that you can't change code that's going to be changing? That sounds pretty terrible.

Comment: Well do suggest whatever minimal change you think can solve the problem. If I can do that without breaking the rest of the architecture then I might take my time to make changes in all these modules.
and no cant change lower modules which these modules import

Comment: @WayneWerner I can import the module, and play around with imported instance. Yes it sounds terrible but cant really explain much without revealing the product logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a concrete implementation of what I proposed in the comments:

```
#File temp.py
var1 = 1
var2 = 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print var1+var2
```

I'm calling it via another file run.py. The key is to have another `dict` like class that is immune against any changes to the variables that the module might change upon importing/running it. This dictionary holds the variables whose value you want to change.

```
#File: run.py
class UpdatedDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key != "var1":
            super(UpdatedDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)

u = UpdatedDict({"var1": 10, '__name__': '__main__'})
exec open("temp.py").read() in u  #u here is the globals() for the module.
```

**Output**

```
~/Temp$ python run.py
12  #Yay!
```

---

**Note**: This is a quick and dirty implementation and is only meant to show you the way you can do it. I'd suggest going through `runpy` and make this code look more robust. The way it stands right now, it is a proper definition of *hackish*

Comment: This is excellent! Thanks a ton for this. :) You saved my 2 days probably for need of going through all legacy scripts and making needed changes to them without breaking rest of the architecture.

Comment: While this works, any work saved by doing this is likely to be outweighed by the extra work generated when people have to deal with it. It creates extremely tight, nonlocal coupling that's impossible to detect by reading the code it modifies, making it even more difficult to change any part of this system. People are going to be so damn confused when their assignment statements are completely ignored.

Comment: @user2357112 Couldn't agree more! I hope the OP realizes what you just said.

Comment: I realise this and agree to you both, but at the same time, this is going to suit for my specific usecase without making any mess in the system. Thank you.